# Check whether number is even or odd without using any operator

Tags: c

Is it possible to check whether a number is even or odd in c without using any operator?

Comment: Do you mean _arithmetic_ operator? To do something useful in C without any operators at all is really hard.

Comment: Without operator?????

Comment: Normally we'd use mod 2==0 to do this. But if this is some kind of class challenge, you could convert it to a string, grab the last digit, then look it up in an array map thus returning true or false if it's odd.

Comment: @Ultimater: how would you grab the last character of the string without using an operator?

Comment: might be better suited to codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's impossible. You can't even call a function without using the operator `()`. OP, be more specific!

Comment: @FUZxxl: I know `()` counts as an operator in C++, but is this also true for C?

Comment: @PaulR Yes. See ISO 9899:2011 §6.5.2.2 titled “Function calls” which is a subsection of §6.5.2 “Postfix operators.”

Comment: @FUZxxl: interesting - I didn't know that - thanks for the pointing me at the relevant sections in the standard.

Comment: @PaulR Okay, I found a way to do it without operators. This is amazing.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are talking about **no arithmetic operator**

In this case you can ask yourself, in binary what represents the least significant bit (bit 0)?

So you can test that bit to know if a number is odd or even:

```
if (number & 0x01)
{
   // odd number
}
else
{
   // even number
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure Bitwise-And is considered an arithmetic operator since it works on numbers and returns numbers.

Comment: @LPs The C standard calls `&` a *bitwise* operator (cf. ISO 9899:2011§6.5.10 “bitwise AND operator). The logical operators are `&&`, `||`, and `!`.

Comment: I disagree. `&&` would be a logical operator while `&` is surely a bitwise operator. The question is whether a bitwise operator would also be considered arithmetic.

Comment: @FUZxxl, Ultimater yes, my error. I was goggoling about [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Arithmetic_operators). It is a bitwise operator.

Comment: @Ultimater Bitwise and operates on a sequence of bits and returns a sequence of bits. That this sequence of bits can be interpreted as a number is coincidental.

Comment: Good point molbdnilo. Didn't think of that in terms of coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that actually works, it cheats a little though. The result is encapsulated in a structure with one member, which is `1` if the number is odd and `0` otherwise:

```
struct oddness {
    unsigned int oddness : 1;
} isodd(int x) {
    struct oddness o = { x };
    return o;
}
```

This works because assignment of a value to a bitfield causes truncation when out of range. Thanks to [kkk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1853605/) for the general approach. The `=` token in this code is not an operator, it is part of the declaration syntax of the C programming language, cf. ISO 9899:2011§6.7 “Declarations.”

*Look! No operators mom!*

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The result is in the one struct member of the result. So use it like this: `isodd(x).oddness`

Answer (score -1):

How about this one liner

```
#define ISODD(x) (x&0x01)?"Yes":"No"
```

Okay after a bit of thought I came up with this

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned int bit:1;
} bitwise_t;

int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    bitwise_t x ;
    x.bit   =  atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d",  x.bit );
    return 0;
}
```

One more Edit :

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int bit:1;
} bitwise_t;

int isodd( int x )
{
    bitwise_t a;
    memcpy ( &a, &x , sizeof(a)) ;
    return a.bit;
}
```

Comment: This one uses  two operators: The bitwise AND operator `&` and the conditional operator `?:`.

Comment: Okay its kind of annoying but why down Vote and what is wrong with the next two edits ?

Comment: @kkk Function call is also an operator, so is `sizeof`, unary `&` and access to structure members. The rest of the approach is pretty cool though.

Comment: @kkk And no, I didn't downvote you. You could implement `isodd` like this though, as initialization syntax is technically not an assignment operator and `return` is not an operator either: `struct oddness { unsigned int isodd:1; }; isodd(int x) { struct oddness o = { x }; return x; }`

Comment: Note that function call is an operator, too and so is unary `&` and `sizeof`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int number;
printf("Enter a number to check even or odd");
scanf("%d", &number);
if(( number >> 1) <<1==number)
      printf("%d is even.", number);
else
      printf("%d is odd.", number);    
getch();
```

}

Comment: I belive >> and << count as operators unfortunetly.

Comment: The result of bitshifting a negative value to the right is implementation-defined in C; attempts to bitshift negative values to the left result in _undefined behavior_.